# Retain state of timer between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to retain the state of the timer between two fragments so that it starts again from the interval 
already passed while switching between two fragments inside a single activity,rather than starting from beginning.

```
countDownTimer = new QRTimer(startTime, 1000);
      countDownTimer.start();
       long minute=startTime/1000*60;
      tv_total.setText(tv_total.getText() + String.valueOf(minute));
```

Comment: define time in activity and use in fragment

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Single Activity & Multiple Fragments mechanism then you can maintain your timer in Activity which is instantiate once. And by using Fragment's getActivity() method you can access the timer in all fragments.